# cucumber AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException

Tags: java, automation, cucumber

I'm getting an AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException with the following case, I dont find any reason for this problem. Please help!

scenario

```
 Scenario Outline: Testing the stars hotel filter
    When the <star> stars hotel filter is clicked
    Then all hotels are <star> stars
    Examples:
    |  star  |
    |    1   |
    |    2   |
    |    3   |
    |    4   |
    |    5   |
```

step file

```
    @When("^the ([^\\\"]*) stars hotel filter is clicked$")
    public void theStarStarsHotelFilterIsClicked(String star) {
        hotelPage.activateStarsFilter(star);
    }

    @Then("^all hotels are ([^\\\"]*) stars$")
    public void allHotelsAreStarStars(String star) throws InterruptedException {
        hotelPage.checkHotelStars(star);
    }

    @When("^the ([^\\\"]*) filter is clicked$")
    public void thePriceOrderFilterIsClicked(String priceOrder) {
        hotelPage.activatePriceFilter(priceOrder);
    }
```

error

```
cucumber.runtime.AmbiguousStepDefinitionsException: ✽.When the 5 stars hotel filter is clicked(hotelSearches.feature:16) matches more than one step definition:
  ^the ([^\"]*) filter is clicked$ in HotelSearchesSteps.thePriceOrderFilterIsClicked(String)
  ^the ([^\"]*) stars hotel filter is clicked$ in HotelSearchesSteps.theStarStarsHotelFilterIsClicked(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty clear:

"the 5 stars hotel filter is clicked"
matches

`@When("^the ([^\\\"]*) filter is clicked$")`

This seems not to be your intension. Maybe change the first expression to:

`@When("^the (\\d+) stars hotel filter is clicked$")`

And do the same to the second expression. Make it more specific.

Comment: Could you teach me whats the meaning of ([^\\"]* and (\d+) please, newbie here. Thank you!

Comment: @Fran - in short, `"([^\\\"]*)"` means "any String (including empty String) that doesn't contain double-quote characters", and `"(\\d+)"` means "any sequence of one or more digits".  So it makes sense to use the latter if you're expecting the input to be a number.